# GeoTools dependency not found by the m2e Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e, geotools

I need to use GeoTools in a JAVA-Project I am developing using Eclipse and the m2e plugin.

I have configured the following repository in my pom.xml:

```
<repository>
    <id>osgeo</id>
    <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
    <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools</url>
</repository>
```

I get no result when I search for "gt-shapefile" in the Dependencies->Add dialog. Is there maybe another repository? I notice that the "gt-shapefile" library exists under http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/org/geotools but it doesn't make a difference if I change the repository's URL to that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this helps anyone in the future:

Finding the dependency didn't work using the user-interface method, so I tried editing the pom.xml file by hand as described in the link below (see point 5) and it worked!

http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/eclipse.html#adding-jars-to-your-project